# How to use UIPickerView to show date months and Year(Upto 2015)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

Hey can i use a UIPickerView to display date, month and Year(Only upto 2015) in IOS?. Please help me with a coded idea..

Comment: You need to implement `UIDatePicker`.

Comment: As @NimitParekh said, use a `UIDatePicker` and apply maximumDate to it. You'll be all set

Comment: but how to set the year upto 2015??... i want the year to be upto 2015 only...

Comment: You can set datePicker maximumDate for which you need the max date. then it will show you up to that date only. Like [datePicker setMaximumDate:maxDate]; maxDate should be like 31/12/2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as that just copy paste this code in your `viewdidload`. Here in this code the `setMaximumDate` set the what you want for. That will be your **Max Date**. Here in this piece of code I used `max date` as `TODAYS DATE`.

```
  UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [datePicker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use UIDatePicker for that:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/

There are quite a few code samples that you can use. For example:
http://www.makemegeek.com/uidatepicker-example-ios/

Good luck